# Question on positronium lifetime

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, positronium

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positronium) I could get that lifetime of orthopositronium (spin of electron and positron point in same direction) is

$t=\frac{9h}{4m_ec^2\alpha^6(\pi^2-9)}$

And parapositronium

$t=\frac{h}{\pi m_ec^2\alpha^5}$

How do I derive those using QED equations?

Comment: A derivation would be too long for a Stack Exchange answer.

Comment: [Positronium: A theoretical lifetime calculation](https://scholarship.tricolib.brynmawr.edu/bitstream/handle/10066/10512/Muluneh_thesis_2003.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y) takes six pages to derive the para lifetime, and the background required to understand the derivation takes a quantum field theory textbook.